# How to return only number using count?

Tags: mysql, node.js, knex.js

I'm using `knex` and I would like to return only the number instead of `RowDataPacket`, this is my code:

```
let totalUsers = await ctx.db('user')
    .join('group', 'user.id', 'group.user_id')
    .where('user.first_name', 'like', '%' + firstName + '%')
    .count()
    .first();

console.log(totalUsers);
```

essentially this returns:

> RowDataPacket { 'count(*)': 1 }

I would like to get only `1`, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you can use this to get the count value:

```
let count = totalUsers["count(*)"];
```

I also think the drivers for the different DBRMSes will return different names for the count variables. For SQL Server, for instance, the count field didn't have a proper name when I tried, just `''`. So to make it work in all SQL dialects I would give the count an alias in the SQL query, like so:

```
.count('* AS c')
```

You can then access it like this:

```
let count = totalUsers["c"];
```

Comment: I honestly don't like the way to get the records count.. I hope the `knex` team will add a method `countRows()` or something like which return only the number